# Add flags on condition

Tags: highcharts

How can I add a flag, where the value of x - 1 is different then value of x, can it be done directly on the chart?

`x is [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]` so when I get the pair 1, 3 I want to put a flag on 3, and say that something has changed.

Comment: Loop the data in advance to create your flag series with flags in the correct positions.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Try posting a jsfiddle of what you have tried. More people will try to help that way.